# Relative Pronouns Summary

Tags: pronombres

I am learning Spanish, and relative pronouns are a tricky matter. Is the following guide correct?

1. Defining relative clause without a preposition: only "que"

> La mujer que está sentada aquí es rubia.

> La computadora que es rápida es mi favorite.

2. Defining relative clause with a preposition for inanimate objects: only "el que" construction

> El libro del que te hablé es “Alicia en el País de las Maravillas.”

3. Defining relative clause with a preposition for people: only "quien" or "el que" constructions

> La mujer con la que tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa.

> La mujer con quien tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa.

4. Supplementary relative clause for inanimate objects: only "el que" construction

> Las mesas, las que son de plástico, son baratas.

5. Supplementary relative clause for people: interchangeably "quien" or "el que" constructions

> Mi tía, quien es doctora, me va a visitar hoy.

> Mi tía, la que es doctora, me va a visitar hoy.

6. Any relative clause with a compound preposition: preferably "el cual" construction

> Los coches delante de los cuales has aparcado son de Francia.

> Cerré la puerta, detrás de la cual la fiesta continuaba.

> Las chicas junto a las cuales está mi esposa son mis hijas.

However, I was talking to my abuela, and she said that in the following sentence, not only can "la" be dropped, but if "la" were to be included, it should be "la cual," not "la que."

> Su ayuda, que es muy apreciada, es necesaria ahora.

> Su ayuda, la cual es muy apreciada, es necesaria ahora.

This would obviously disagree with what I have written above. She swears that this sounds the best but doesn't know why.

Comment: You are only supposed to ask one question at a time. Not a complete summary of a complicated thing like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a problem with this one:

> Las mesas, las que son de plástico, son baratas.

This is not wrong, but what's between the commas is not a supplementary clause. I'm not sure what it is, but it looks like an apposition: you could take it on its own and make it the subject of the sentence. It translates to “The tables, the ones which are plastic, are cheap”. You need to use either *que* by itself, or *las cuales*.

This one sounds very artificial, but is correct:

> Mi tía, quien es doctora, me va a visitar hoy.

This one is like the first one, and the natural solution is to use only *que* or *quien*:

> Mi tía, la que es doctora, me va a visitar hoy.

Comment: So for comma-separated AND no-comma-separated relative clauses, use que for the most natural-sounding construction? And reserve quien for when there is a preposition in the clause? Based on what you're saying, "el que" sounds like it would unnecessarily interrupt the flow, at least in the English equivalent. Like I said, I've spoken to many native speakers about this, including my abuela who is both a native speaker and a very well-rounded Spanish teacher, and even she found herself becoming confused.

Comment: Perhaps this type of question is comparable to phrasal verbs in English. In some cases there's a ton of gray area in some phrasal verbs as to which preposition you can use, and other times it's only hit or miss.

Comment: I would argue that *que*, when possible, is always more "natural" in the sense that it's simple and neutral in terms of formality. With a preposition, it's prep + *quien* or prep + article + *cual*. The article + *que* construction is special and should not be used in sentences like these.

Answer (score 0):

I find some problems with point 5:

- *Mi tía, que es doctora, me va a visitar hoy* (more common)
- *Mi tía, la cual es doctora, me va a visitar hoy*
- *Mi tía, quien es doctora, me va a visitar hoy* (less common)

Mean: *My aunt, who is a doctor, is visiting me today*.

But

- *Mi tía, la que es doctora, me va a visitar hoy*

Means: *My aunt, the one who is a doctor, is visiting me today*.

So your abuela is right.

Comment: So in supplementary-type relative clauses for people, are "que," "el cual," and "quien" preferable? I find that so confusing.

Comment: The reason why this is so bloody confusing for me is that websites like StudySpanish and SpanishDict have “que” ONLY for defining relative clauses. They don’t have any uses of “que” when it’s separated by a comma; those places ALWAYS use “el que” and “quien.”